# Replacing part of a string using a For loop

Tags: python, string

I need to get a user to enter a sentence for an assignment. Using a `for` loop, I then need to replace all spaces with `%20` in order to prep the string to be used as a URL. I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
sentence = str(input("Please enter sentence:"))
space = (" ")

for space in sentence:
    space.replace(sentence, space, "%20", 500)
print(sentence)
```

This is what I have entered so far but it is completely wrong.

Comment: You did it the "right" way. This is not a very good use case for for loops.

Comment: Strings are immutable, `replace` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the string in place.

Comment: @Barmar. While I mostly agree with closing this question, I don't think that you have chosen a valid duplicate. OP is asking about replacing characters using loops. URLs are totally incidental here.

Comment: @roganjosh. Odd, as I'm on mobile. I swear that usually doesn't happen :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist The only reason he's trying to replace characters is because he wants to do url-encoding.

Comment: @Barmar. The only reason he's trying to replace characters is because his teacher told him to, and his teacher is focusing of for loops right now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point, didn't notice it's an assignment.

Comment: You're using the variable `space` for multiple things.

Answer (score 2):

String in Python can't be modified. The `replace()` function returns a new string with all the replacements done. You need to assign this result somewhere. So you can do:

```
sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "%20")
```

If you want to do it with a loop, you need to build the result in another variable.

```
new_sentence = ""
for char in sentence:
    if char == " ":
        new_sentence += "%20"
    else:
        new_sentence += char
```

There's no point in using `replace()` in the loop.

Comment: I swear I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: Good job renaming the variables when you did it. :)

Comment: Ha! Yeah, I had to, otherwise it would have been obvious.

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace everything after the first line with `print(sentence.replace(" ","%20"))`

or, if you really must use a loop:

```
s = ''
for x in sentence:
    if x == ' ':
        s += "%20"
    else:
        s += x
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got a few problems here:

1. the variable **space** that you define before the loop is equal to " " but then you're using the same name for the for loop variable, which is going to iterate through the string the **sentence** string, in the loop, it's going to use the value defined by the loop.
2. You're giving the replace method too many arguments, it's a method of the string object so you don't need to pass it the large string to operate on [Replace Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)
3. You're using  the replace method on the **space** string and not on the **sentence** string

Good way to do it in real life:

```
old = ' '  
new = '%20'

sentence = str(input("Please enter sentence:"))
print(sentence.replace(old,new))
```

The way your teacher is probably after:

```
sentence = str(input("Please enter sentence:"))
old = ' '  
new = '%20'
newSentence = ''

for letter in sentence:
    if letter == ' ':
        newSentence += new
    else:
        newSentence += letter


print(newSentence)
```

Comment: Hi Kieran, Thanks for your help. Not only does the code work and it is 100% in line with what my lecturer is looking for. it all makes a lot of sense and has really cleared up the problem in my head. thanks :D

Comment: No worries mate! Glad I could help